# Wiki Cleanup - Rejects/Approvals

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

I saw some unfilled wiki entries for some of the tags on the CG site, so I figured I'd fill them in. For this, I simply copy-and-pasted the info from the SO tags. Some of my suggestions were approved and others were rejected.

[needless content removed]

### EDIT:

It probably was not a good idea for me to be lazy by copy-and-pasting from SO to begin with. I've made corrections to the wiki excerpts for some of the language tags that fit better with the CG site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because somebody approved it for SO does not mean it's going to get approved here. FWIW, I'd probably have rejected both of them, but, I will say that the C one is probably slightly more acceptable than the C++ one, which is just too confusing (IMHO).

On an unrelated note, I'd probably have approved [this edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/277). So I'm absolutely not taking sides here. :-)

Comment: I do understand that what is good for SO is not necessarily so here (especially some tags over others). I was taking a lazy approach here. I guess my point is, if you're going to reject one, why not reject them all?

Comment: To your edit: I didn't think you were. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're right: I should have rejected the C one too. Sorry.

The point of the tag wiki isn't to be an definition of the tag name: it's to help people know whether to use a tag for their question or not.

As an aside, I'm not even sure we should *have* a C++ tag - there are few good reasons for restricting a question to one language; in the case of C++ template metaprogramming questions, [compile-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compile-time) is probably more useful.

Comment: I do understand that - my mistake in the first place for just being lazy. I did go in and re-suggest new excerpts for all the language-specific tags, and added that language-specific challenges are discouraged (if that actually helps).